# Custom Menu in Themes not working even in Twenty Eleven theme

Tags: menus

I am currently having problems with a Wordpress installation.

The remote site I was supposed to theme uses WP 3.2 so I used 3.2

I created a theme that supports custom menus and it works fine on my localhost. But when I uploaded it to the remote test site, I notice that I can't add any custom menu. I see that the "Theme Locations" thing on the left side isn't there.

So I tried to revert to the TwentyEleven theme and I still get the same situation.

Disabling all plugins doesn't work either.

I notice that I have file permissions error since I get a 403 error in the Ajax request when I try to upload any file using the file uploader. Could that be one of the cause why my custom menu is acting weird?

Comment: It is usually near-impossible to answer functional questions without being able to **see the actual code** in question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem here is that, on your remote test site, you **haven't created any custom menus**. Try creating one or more custom menus, and then the "Theme Locations" meta box should appear, enabling you to assign your defined custom menus to defined Theme locations.

As is shown in [the Codex entry for **Appearance -> Menus**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel), the "Theme Locations" meta box is disabled if no custom menus are defined:

[image: Appearance->Menus Admin screen with no custom menus defined]